# How many nether fortresses are there in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I always thought that there was only 2 nether fortresses in Minecraft: Xbox One edition, but now I question myself maybe there are more.

How many nether fortresses are there?

Answer (score 1):

there is an infinite amount of nether fortresses that can generate you just need to explore

Comment: the nether is limted so i know that is wrong

Comment: if you go too far in one direction eventually you will hit bedrock obviously you will have to break though some blocks but it eventually is bedrock